# how to dynamic protect excel sheet according to a cell value in that sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel workbook with n sheets

Every sheet has a cell that contains a value which decides that sheet will be protected or not (for instance, A1)

So how can I dynamic set excel sheet protected according to the cell above by excel formula or using VBA script? It 's similar to the hyperlink function in excel, which I can dynamic set hyperlink in a cell by excel formula

Thanks

Comment: You cannot protect a sheet using a formula. So, only VBA remains. Did you try anything by your own?

Comment: I only think about 2 solutions above, but I prefered to use excel formula than VBA. If it's impossible to proctect sheet by formula, then I have to accept using VBA